# Is there a way to commit changes to remote server from within gitx?

Tags: git

Trying to get my head around git, github and gitx but struggling a little. Wondered if I am missing anything, but I can not seem to find a way to commit to remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the push command. Use `git push --help` to see the man page and checkout this [Git Reference](http://gitref.org/index.htmlence) for more help.

The current official version of GitX does not have push or other remote operations. I have a fork of GitX that adds those and more. https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx/downloads (download the zip file)

Comment: great forkage, cheers!!